# Multiple tag id in post loop

Tags: wordpress, tags

How can i add Multiple tag in WP_Query(). So, I have three tags :

1. first name (tag id="10")
2. Middle name (tag id="20")
3. Last name (tag id="30")

   ```
   $args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post',
       'paged'=>$paged,
       'posts_per_page' => 15,             
       'orderby' => 'date',
       **'tag_id' =>  array(10,20,30),**           
       'order' => 'DESC'
       );
   ```

Of course above does not work.

How do I display posts from multiple tags?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [`tag__in`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters) parameter that is meant specifically for this:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'paged'=> $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 15,             
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'tag__in' =>  array(10,20,30),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using WP_Query then you can do like below.

```
//Display posts that are tagged with both tag id 37 and tag id 47:
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag__and' => array( 37, 47 ) ) );
```

OR

```
//To display posts from either tag id 37 or 47, you could use tag as mentioned above, or explicitly specify by using tag__in:
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag__in' => array( 37, 47 ) ) );
```

For more you can visit the official link https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query